# How to not count NULL values in DENSE_RANK()?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have the following table:

```
col
NULL
1
1
2
```

Then I select:

```
SELECT col, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col) as rnk from table
```

Then I get:

```
col  rnk
NULL 1
1    2
1    2
2    3
```

What I want to get is this:

```
col  rnk
NULL NULL
1    1
1    1
2    2
```

But if I query:

```
SELECT col, CASE WHEN col IS NOT NULL THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col) END as rnk from table
```

Then I get:

```
col  rnk
NULL NULL
1    2
1    2
2    3
```

Is there a way to disregard `NULL`s when ranking, other than using a `WHERE` clause? I have some other columns whose rows cannot be omitted.

Comment: BQ or Teradata?  They are very different.  Tag correctly!

Comment: BQ now supports standard SQL.

Comment: "standard SQL" <> "Teradata SQL"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `partition by`:

```
SELECT col,
       (CASE WHEN col IS NOT NULL
             THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN col IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
                                     ORDER BY col
                                    )
        END) as rnk
FROM table;
```

Comment: just to clarify - this answer is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . This query will work in any SQL engine that supports `dense_rank()`, as far as I know.

Comment: but not with BigQuery Legacy SQL :o) as PARTITION BY in legacy SQL allows ONLY field name and not expression

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . Duly noted.  It is has been a while since I've used the legacy interface.  Glad they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT col, CASE WHEN col IS NOT NULL THEN rnk END AS rnk
FROM (
  SELECT 
    col, (col IS NULL) AS tmp, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tmp ORDER BY col) AS rnk 
  FROM table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
col,
case 
   when col is not null -- to override dense_rank 3 to NULL for the NULL record
   then dense_rank() over (order by col nulls last)
   end as rnk
from table 
order by col asc
;
```

gives result

```
       COL        RNK
---------- ----------
                     
         1          1
         1          1
         2          2
```